# How to make button clicked and get its argument value on loading a page

Tags: javascript, html

Hi Friends am in need your all help that i got an scenario that navigating from one html page to another page

### Clear explanation

navigating from html page 1 to html page2 which contains three buttons with different id. i have to make the first button to be selected on page load and have to get all its argument value onclick event.

### html page 1

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="htmlpage2.html">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### html page 2

```
     <html>
        <body>
        <button id="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
        </button>
         <button id="button2" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
         </button>
         <button id="button3" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
        </button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function save(name,shape,made){
          alert(name);
          alert(shape);
          alert(made);
        }
        </script>

    </body>
        </html>

## scenario ##
On navigating to html page2 i have to make the button with id="button1" to be clicked default and have to get alert(); as if give in the save function hope will get a better response thank You
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: if calling function is the only objective, why not call save('Ice','cube','water') directly onload?

Comment: Can directly do onload where as here am getting function save as undefined and based on that scenario i have to make more progression in my project

Comment: If save() is undefined, you may be calling it from the wrong place, see answer below :)

Comment: Can you show what code you are using now that calls the button click?

Comment: can i show the screenshot of it

Comment: Just add it to the end of your question, otherwise yep, that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function save(name,shape,made){
      alert(name);
      alert(shape);
      alert(made);
    }

    $("#button1").trigger("click")
    </script>
```

Comment: i updated my answer, but i see someone else already went for that solution, hehe

Comment: nope still getting the same error save is not defined? :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/txwssL9s/1/   Here it works, maybe you are having a different problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <button id="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
    </button>
     <button id="button2" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
     </button>
     <button id="button3" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
    </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function save(name,shape,made){
      alert(name);
      alert(shape);
      alert(made);
    }
    document.getElementById("button1").click();
    </script>

</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
document.getElementById('button1').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
    </button>
    <button id="button2" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
    </button>
    <button id="button3" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save('Ice','cube','water')">click
    </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function save(name, shape, made) {
            alert(name);
            alert(shape);
            alert(made);
        }

        document.getElementById("button1").click();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If not using jquery,

```
document.getElementById('button1').click();
```